# How to smoothen black edges generated due to affine transformation using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, rotation

In order to remove black portion on sides of an image (generated due to affine transformation), I have added original image with 90 degree angle rotated image. The resulting image is not completely smooth on some places where black region existed. The ultimate aim i am seeking is to remove the black portion generated on sides near border due to affine transformation. The MATLAB code and resultant pics are shown below:

```
I=imread('cg.jpg');
figure,imshow(I),title('Original');
tform=affine2d([1 0 0 ; 0.05 1 0 ; 0 0 1]);
II=imwarp(I, tform);
figure,imshow(II),title('Affine');
zeropixels = II == 0;
III=imrotate(II,90,'bilinear');
II(zeropixels) = III(zeropixels);
figure,imshow(III),title('Rotated');
figure,imshow(II),title('Corrected');
```

Can anyone suggest ways to smoothen the resultant image or propose a better solution? Please note that actual image used in my project is colored image having some content also.

[image]
[[image]
[[image]

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you want and why you're currently doing what it is that you're doing. Where are the black portions coming from? Why don't you just index for everything except the portions? Why would you superimpose (assuming you mean add?) an image with a 90 degree rotated version of itself? More context would be helpful.

Comment: @Falimond: Kindly check the updated question.

Comment: You may want to look into Hough transforms, but this really all seems like overkill for the simple task of adjusting/filling in an image border.